# View query used in Data Factory Copy Data operation

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I'm doing a pretty vanilla 'Copy Data' operation. One dataset to another.

Can I view the query being used to perform the copy operation? Apparently, it's a syntax error, but I've only used drag-and-drop menus. Here's the error:

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
> database operation failed. Please search error to get more
> details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near the keyword 'from'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=156,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=156,State=1,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near the keyword 'from'.,},],'

Extra context
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hi @Daniel Scott,Can you try using the query option in source and write the select query to check if you are still getting same error?

Comment: Sure, I can write it as a query. But my question was whether or not we can see the query being used for the 'table' operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.Clear Schema and import Schema again. 
2. This mostly happens when there are some changes to table schema after creating pipeline and datasets. verify once.
3.The schema and datasets should be refreshed when there are some changes in the SQL table schema.
4. For table name or view name used in the query, use []. ex: [dbo].[persons]
5. In datasets select table name
6. try to publish before testing.
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same scenario and reproduced the same thing. I didn’t get any error as you can see, the above error mainly happens because of schema.

**Source dataset:**

In source dataset, I manually added and connected to SQL database with Sample SQL table.

[image: Ref1]

**Sink dataset:**

In sink dataset, I added another SQL database with auto create table, write behavior: `Upset`, key column: `PersonID`.

[image: Ref2]

Before execution there is no table on SQL database, then after the execution was successful, I got this sample output in azure SQL database.

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]